# Django Form Processing With Custom Widget

Tags: django, django-forms

I am implementing a star rating system, and I am having trouble getting the form to validate. I am using a custom widget (see code below), and this plugin http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating. When a rating is selected, I am setting the value on the input to be the value of the rating. I want this value on the input to be the value that is cleaned and validated by the form, but right now the form always prompts back that rating is a required field. How do I get my django form to accept the value of the input on this custom widget as the value to validate?

```
class StarRatingsWidget(forms.Widget):

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return mark_safe('<input id="id_star_rating" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.5 data-size="xs" data-glyphicon="false" data-show-caption="false" >')
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to define a default value?

Comment: No, I want a way to send the value of the input element to the form to pass validation. Right now the form fails validation every time because the input is seen as empty.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to provide a correct name for my widget, per django form standards, and implement the `value_from_datadict` method to return the value of the widget.

```
class StarRatingsWidget(forms.Widget):

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return mark_safe('<input name="%s" id="id_rating" type="number" class="rating" value=0 min=0 max=5 step=0.5 data-size="xs" data-glyphicon="false" data-show-caption="false" >' % name)

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        return float(data[name])
```